# Встроенные механизмы шифрования gRPC

Tags: c#, .net-5

Есть ли у gRPC встроенные механизмы шифрования? Если есть, то как их активировать? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: gRPC работает через HTTP/2, и если вы используете HTTPS, то и gRPC запросы через него будут зашифрованы с помощью TLS.

Comment: А возможно ли использовать https при подключении с клиента на .NET 5.0?

Comment: Можно, HTTP/2 поддерживается начиная с .NET Core 3.1. HTTPS поддерживается и на HTTP/1.1 и на HTTP/2.